# Why are the conditionals evaluating to 2

Tags: python, for-loop

```
num = [2, 3]
for k in num:
    if (k % 3) != 0: # I USED TO THIS CONDITION HERE
        print('First print', k)
```

Prints 2

---

```
num = [2, 3]
for k in num:
    if (k % 3): # I DONT UNDERSTAND WHY THIS EVALUATES to True for 2
        print('second print', k)
```

Prints 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to `2 % 3` is `2`.  All non-zero numbers have a boolean value of `True`, so your `if` statement is executed.  `3 % 3`, on the other hand, is `0`.  The boolean value of `0` is `False`, so *that* time the `if` statement is *not* executed.

Answer (score 0):

The result of n%3 will be 2 for 2%3 and 0 for 3%3. All positive numbers are evaluated to True, while 0 is evaluated to false. In your case,

```
 if (2%3):
```

is the same as

```
 if (true):
```